# Parentheses within chemfig are shifted in height

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw a polymer with repeating units using chemfig. However, my opening and closing parentheses are shifted in vertical direction. This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook} \nonstopmode
\input{header}
\begin{document}
\setpolymerdelim()
\chemfig{
    H_3C-[1](-[7]-[1]O-[@{opa,.5}7]-[1]-[7]O-[@{cla,.5}1](=[2]O)(-[7]=[1]CH_2))
}
\makebraces[0pt,45pt]{\!\!\!n}{opa}{cla}
\end{document}
```

with header.tex:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

% Chemfig brackets
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
\edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
\edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
\chemmove{%
\node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right.$};%
\node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
```

The makebraces and setpolymerdelim-part is just copy&paste of the chemfig manual. Below you find an screenshot of the output:

[image: The output of my example. I added a black baseline afterwards.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the first parameter in your call to `\makebraces` to shift them upward. The total brace height is the sum of the two optional parameters (45 pt in your MWE). Keeping that same overall height:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook} \nonstopmode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}

% Chemfig brackets
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
\edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
\edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
\chemmove{%
\node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right.$};%
\node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
{$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}

\begin{document}
\setpolymerdelim()
\chemfig{
    H_3C-[1](-[7]-[1]O-[@{opa,.5}7]-[1]-[7]O-[@{cla,.5}1](=[2]O)(-[7]=[1]CH_2))
}
\makebraces[20pt,25pt]{\!\!\!n}{opa}{cla}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image: shifted braces]

**Edit:**

The individual braces are positioned based on the passed nodes (`opa` and `cla` which are positioned along the bonds. Since the bond are not symmetric, the left brace is lower than the right brace. If you want the braces to be at the same height, you will need to modify the `\makebraces` command. The following sets the two braces at the average `y` for the two points:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook} \nonstopmode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Chemfig brackets
\newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}

\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
\edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
\edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
\chemmove{%
\path let \p1=(#4), \p2=(#5) in node[yshift=(\delimvshift)] at (\x1,0.5*\y1+0.5*\y2)
{$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right.$};%
\path let \p1=(#4), \p2=(#5) in node[yshift=(\delimvshift)] at (\x2,0.5*\y1+0.5*\y2)
{$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}

\begin{document}
\setpolymerdelim()
\chemfig{
    H_3C-[1](-[7]-[1]O-[@{opa,.5}7]-[1]-[7]O-[@{cla,.5}1](=[2]O)(-[7]=[1]CH_2))
}
\makebraces[20pt,25pt]{\!\!\!n}{opa}{cla}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! But still, the left brace is shifted downwards compared with the right one, isn't it?

Comment: @Vincent: Answer updated.